# Exception thrown while converting large sized jpg images

Tags: java

I am trying to **upload the jpg** images & converting same into new **thumbnail** through servlet.
After writing that file on disk, my requirment is to create a thumbnail for the same jpg file.
And for that I used following code...

```
//code to upload & write image file on disk goes here..

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
img.createGraphics().drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File(sourceFile)).getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH),0,0,null);

ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File(thumbFile));
```

Above code **goes well for small files**. But when its comes towards file of size **5MB**, it copies, but fails to convert it into thumbnail & throws

```
Exception in thread ""http-bio-8888"-exec-63" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at UploadFile.doPost(UploadFile.java:67).
```

Please guide me.

Comment: *"But when its comes towards file of size 5MB"* With image compression techniques the way they are, a '5MB file' might account for 10-150MB (or beyond) of data in memory once expanded to an actual image.  How big is the image (in pixels)?  Is it gray-scale or color?  Does it include transparency?

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the heap size by using the '-Xms' and `-Xmx` command line option to the java interpreter (sets initial heap size and maximum heap size, respectively).

Check out this blog entry on [Playing with JVM / Java Heap Size](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap.html).